How to define style for OpenRewrite to reorder Imports (OrderImports)
I am searching for an example rewrite.yml -file to use the org.openrewrite.java.OrderImports-plugin to define a custom ordering for the import statements.
I searched all over the documentation and the internet - but without succes - yet... ;-)

I found what I searched for: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/blob/main/rewrite-java/src/main/resources/META-INF/rewrite/spring.yml
Here is an example of an OrderImports-configuration considering a custom ordering of the imports.

Here you go:
type: specs.openrewrite.org/v1beta/recipe
name: org.myUser.MyRecipe
displayName: My custom recipe
description: Fix all the things.
recipeList:
  - org.openrewrite.java.OrderImports

That's from using the Moderne recipe builder at https://app.moderne.io/recipes/builder
And then using "Add to builder" from https://app.moderne.io/recipes/org.openrewrite.java.OrderImports

Hmm, thanks - but that's what I already found somehow. But then the plugin will order the imports in "IntelliJ-way" - but  I want to specify a custom (company-fixed) ordering. Therefore you need to specify a style. But how can I do that??

Ah I skipped over the title and only read your question body; sorry about that! Did you already come across this section of our docs that explain how to define custom styles?
https://docs.openrewrite.org/reference/yaml-format-reference#style-example
